# Java 8 Generic use of Stream.collect()

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream

I'll start by acknowledging that erasure might make this impossible. Here's what I'm trying to do, which doesn't work:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Suppliers {
    public static <CollectionType, T> CollectionType<T>
    fill(CollectionType colltype, Supplier<T> gen, int n) {
        return Stream.generate(gen)
            .limit(n)
            .collect(colltype::new, colltype::add, colltype::addAll);
    }
}
```

The goal is to generate an instance of `CollectionType` and fill it with `n` items using `gen`. This form of `collect()` does instantiate a new collection but it's not clear to me whether that type can be passed through via the argument list of `fill()`. The `fill()` method doesn't have to look exactly this way as long as it instantiates a new collection and fills it up and returns the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but what you want is along the lines of:

```
<T, C extends Collection<T>> C fill(Supplier<T> gen, 
                                    int n, 
                                    Supplier<C> factory) { 
    return Stream.generate(gen)
                 .limit(n)
                 .collect(factory, C::add, C::addAll);
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
HashSet<String> strings = fill(() -> "Foo", 10, HashSet::new);
```

This technique is used in methods like the 4-arg version of `Collectors.toMap()`.

Comment: Actually the same is done by `Collectors.toCollection()`, so `.collect(toCollection(factory))` also could be used.

Comment: It always looks so easy when you do it, Brian. Thanks again.

Comment: (unrelated note) Brian - [here is a question about Split Data Model concept in JCiP](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/307389/31260), I would appreciate if you take a look (been thinking about answering it myself but figured that you might be interested)